# Will using FileStream in SQL Server increase database size?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, filestream

I am using AppHarbor for hosting my website and currently it offers only 20MB free space. I want to store PDF files using SQL Server's FileStream column. Would using FileStream increase the database size because FileStream basically stores on hard disk as I know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: here more detail on [FileStream ] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `FILESTREAM` data becomes part of the database, in the sense that it has its own `FILEGROUP`(s) and can (should be) be backed up through SQL backups - I would answer yes.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not increase the size of the database as the files are not stored in the Database.
Please read the following "FILESTREAM Design and Implementation Considerations" --google is your best friend